# Promises in Ember CLI/Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I'm trying to write a ember-cli-deploy plugin and can really use some help with promises. In my index.js for the main plugin, I have the following code
index.js:

```
prepare: function(context) {
    ...
    ...
    var awsDeploymentOptions = {....};
    this._awsCodeDeployClient = new CodeDeployClient({awsDeploymentOptions: awsDeploymentOptions});

}
upload: function() {
    ...
    ...
    var uploadPromise = (awsDeploymentOptions.revision.revisionType === 'S3') ? this._awsS3Client.upload(filesToUpload, this.readConfig('s3UploadOptions')) : new Promise().resolve();
    return uploadPromise.then(function(result){return this._awsCodeDeployClient.createDeployment(result)}.bind(this));
}
```

The above works as expected and the promises get resolved properly.

If I change the above code to:

```
return uploadPromise.then(this._awsCodeDeployClient.createDeployment);
```

the code fails. Then, I tried the following, which fails as well:

```
return uploadPromise.then(this._awsCodeDeployClient.createDeployment.bind(this));
```

In both the cases above, it complains of undefined variables/properties inside createDeployment method, which is defined as below:

```
createDeployment: function(s3FileUploadOptions) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //This is where the problem lies. this is never resolved
        //to this module's 'this' and I cannot access this.deploymentOptions
        //Any reference to 'this' variable causes an error
        var awsDeploymentOptions = this.awsDeploymentOptions;
        this.codeDeploy.createDeployment(this.awsDeploymentOptions, function(error, data) {
            if (error)
                reject(error); // an error occurred
            else resolve({awsDeploymentId:data.deploymentId}); // successful response. Return deployment Id
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the two scenarios above?

Comment: Could you please: a) indent your code properly, and b) reduce it to the part that is relevant to your question? I'm pretty sure all that AWS code is irrelevant noise.

Comment: try this. var that = this; return uploadPromise.then(this._awsCodeDeployClient.createDeployment.bind(that));

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
return uploadPromise.then(result => this._awsCodeDeployClient.createDeployment(result));
```

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) keep the scope from the calling context.